# Query function not executed between <div> element

Tags: posts, wp-query, functions, query-posts

I'm wondering why the following code is not executed between the  element it's put in. I know sort of how to fix, but I'm not sure if that's the best solution.

My code:

**First function**

```
function myfunction1($args = array()) {

    var_dump($args);

    $output = null;

    $output .= '<div id="mydivelement">';
    $output .= myfunction2( $args );
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;


}
```

**And the second function (myfunction2)**

```
function myfunction2($args) {

        $options = $args;

/* get post types */
    $default_post_types = explode(' ',$options['post_type']);
        if ($default_post_types[0] == 'any') {
           $default_post_types = 'any';
       }

    /* default args */
    $args = array(
            'post_type'         => $default_post_types
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );



    if ($query->have_posts()) :


        require_once dpf_path . 'frontstyle/dpf-front.php';

    else : 

        require_once dpf_path . 'frontstyle/dpf-cantfind.php';

    endif;

}
```

In the dpf-front.php file are some html elements. The posts that are called in function1 are not between the `<div id="mydivelement"></div>` element. How to do this properly? Thanks!

When I echo the div element it works somehow. Why is that?

Comment: For starters, `myfunction2()` doesn't appear to actually return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requires are just echoing the content, you need to put `ob_start();` before the `if ($query->have_posts()) :`, and `return ob_get_clean();` after the `endif;`.